# Flutter: OS Error: Is a directory, errno = 21)

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Im trying to write the file in external storage,but I got this exception:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.filedownload/files/videos/demo/test/ba90098ad645d2f70569e3bf9332db53_69.m3u8' (OS Error: Is a directory, errno = 21))
```

Please guide.

My Code :

```
var testdir =await new Directory(directory.path + '/' + key).create(recursive: true);                           
return File(directory.path + '/' + key)
        .writeAsBytesSync(response.bodyBytes);`
```

Answer (score 3):

It's my mistake, I tried to write my file in directory folder without actual file that's the issue

Comment: Hello how did you solve this issue , pleaase explain me ?

Comment: @Kafi Try saving the file/image with an extension such as `file.saveTo(testDirectory.path + '/imageName.jpg')` instead of just `file.saveTo(testDirectory.path)`.